# How to use a "while loop" to iterate in a non-sequential way and update limits of a range?

Tags: python, for-loop, random, while-loop

I'm simplifying an engineering problem as much as possible for this question:

I have a working code like this:

```
import numpy as np
# FUNCTION DEFINITION
def Calculations(a, b):   # a function defined to work based on 2 arguments, a and b
    A = a * b - a
    B = a * b - b
    d = A - B
    return(A, B, d, a, b)

# STORE LIST CREATION
A_list = []
B_list = []
d_list = []
a_list = []
b_list = []   # I will need this list later

# 1st sequential iteration in a for loop
length = np.arange(60, 62.5, 0.5)
for l in length: 
    lower = 50  # this is what I want the program to update based on d
    upper = 70.5  # this is what I want the program to update based on d
    step = 0.5
    width = np.arange(lower, upper, step)
# 2nd for loop, but here I wouldn't like a sequential iteration
    for w in width:
        A_list.append(Calculations(l, w)[0])
        B_list.append(Calculations(l, w)[1])
        d_list.append(Calculations(l, w)[2])
        a_list.append(Calculations(l, w)[3])
        b_list.append(Calculations(l, w)[4])
        
        
print(A_list, " \n")
print(B_list, " \n")
print(d_list, " \n")
print(a_list, " \n")
print(b_list, " \n")
```

This is the way I have it now, but not how I want it to work.

Here, the program iterates each time through the values of **length**(l) in a sequential manner, meaning it evaluates everything for *l=60*, then for *l=60.5* and so on... this is ok, but then, for *l=60* it evaluates first for **w=50**, then for **w=50.5** and so on...

What I want is that, for *l=60* he evaluates for any random value (let's call this **n**) between the 50 (lower) and 70.5 (upper) with a step of 0.5 (step), he will then find a particular **d** as one of the "returned" results, if the **d** is negative then the **n** he used is the new *upper*, if **d** is positive that **n** is the new *lower*, and he will continue to do this until **d** is *zero*.

I will keep trying to figure it out by myself, but any help would be appreciated.

PD:
As I said this example is a simplification of my real problem, as side questions I would like to ask:

- The real condition of while loop to break is not when **d** is *zero*, but the closest possible to *zero*, or phrased in other way, the min() of the abs() values composing the *d_list*. I tried something like:

```
for value in d_list: 
    if value = min(abs(d_list)):      
        print(A_list, " \n")
        print(B_list, " \n")
        print(d_list, " \n")
        print(a_list, " \n")
        print(b_list, " \n")
```

but that's not correct.
I don't want to use a conditions such as `if d < 0.2` because sometimes I will get **d's** like 0.6 and that may be ok, neither do I want a condition like `if d < 1` because then if for example **d = 0.005** I would get a lot of d's before that, satisfying the condition of being < 1, but I only want one for each *l*.

- I also need to find the associated values in the returned lists, for that specific **d**

**EDIT**
I made a mistake earlier in the conditions for new upper and lower based on the obtained value of **d**, I fixed that.
Also, I tried solving the problem like this:

```
length = np.arange(60, 62.5, 0.5)
for l in length: 
    lower_w = 59.5  # this is what I want the program to update based on d
    upper_w = 63  # this is what I want the program to update based on d
    step = 0.5
    width = np.arange(lower_w, upper_w, step)
    np.random.shuffle(width)
    for w in width:
        while lower_w < w < upper_w: 
            A_list.append(Calculations(l,w)[0])
            B_list.append(Calculations(l,w)[1])
            d_list.append(Calculations(l,w)[2])
            a_list.append(Calculations(l,w)[3])
            b_list.append(Calculations(l,w)[4])
            for element in d_list:
                if element < 0:
                    upper = w
                else:
                    lower = w
                if abs(element) < 1 :
                    break
```

But the while loop does not get to break...

Answer (score 0):

Use np.random.shuffle to pick the elements of width in a random order:

```
    width = np.arange(lower, upper, step)
    np.random.shuffle(width)
```

But here you don't really want the second loop, just pick one element from it at random, so use np.range.choice(width):

```
    length = np.arange(60, 62.5, 0.5)
    lower = 50  # this is what I want the program to update based on d
    upper = 70.5  # this is what I want the program to update based on d
    step = 0.5
    for l in length: 
        width = np.arange(lower, upper, step)
        if len(width) == 0:
            width = [lower]
        w = np.random.choice(width)
        (A, B, d, a, b) = Calculations(l, w)
        A_list.append(A)
        B_list.append(B)
        d_list.append(d)
        a_list.append(l)
        b_list.append(w)
        if d < 0:
            lower = w
        elif d:
            upper = w
```

No need to pass a and b in the return of the Calculations function, you can just append the original parameters to a_list and b_list.
Note that you will run into an error if your lower and upper bound are identical, because the list will just be empty, so you need to fill in the list with a bound if it returns [].

Comment: But _w_ is undefined here

Comment: what did you attempted to do with the "if statement" here?